# how to add dynamic value using ternary operator in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

In my jsp page i am adding title attribute dynamically in anchor using this code.

```
<c:set var="titleAttributeValue" value="${(anchorListfields[3] != '') ? 'title=${anchorListfields[3]}' : ''}" scope="page" />
```

but rather than showing the value of title attribute in anchor it showing like this  `<a href="/content/aib/personal/home/iwanto.html" rel="nofollow" title="${anchorListfields[3]}"><span><span>Start my Business</span><i></i></span></a>`

how can i achieve this where is my error in syntax

Answer (score 0):

You codes seems to be working.

1. Ensure you have JSTL library in your /WEB-INF/lib.
2. Add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` directive to your page.

I am using glassfish 4